# Controlling Events for Nested React Elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

In an effort to add favoriting to a application menu, I'm working on getting onMouseEnter events to fire only on the element that is currently hovered. The problem is that due to these items being nested, onMouseEnter will fire on both the child element and the onMouseEnter of the parent element will also fire.
Ie:

[HTML Nesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOg6r.png)

The ideal behavior would be this:
[Ideal Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D4ry.png)

But the actual behavior is this:
[Actual Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOvXK.png)

I have already tried stopPropogation, but the problem is that there is a separate event listener on each of the menu items (both the L1 and the L2 have their own on mouse enter listeners). As such, capturing the event at the L2 level doesn't stop the event from firing at the L1 level.

Does anyone know of a way to only trigger the L2 event? Ideally, we wanted to be able to keep hover state specific to each item (ie don't have to have pass handlers for "setIsChildElementHovered"), but open to any ideas people have.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the event only on the child element ? If you have some snippets code might to answer your question. thanks :)